# Create pydantic model for Optional field with alias

Tags: python, pydantic

Pydantic model for compulsory field with alias is created as follows

```
class MedicalFolderUpdate(RWModel):
    id : str = Field(alias='_id')
    university : Optional[str]
```

How to add optional field university's alias name 'school' as like of id?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not documented on the Pydantic website how to use  the typing Optional with the Fields Default besides their allowed types in which they include the mentioned Optional:

> Optional[x] is simply shorthand for Union[x, None]; see Unions below for more detail on parsing and validation and Required Fields for details about required fields that can receive None as a value.

for that, you would have to use their [field customizations](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/custom/) as in the example:

```py
class Figure(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(alias='Name')
    edges: str = Field(default=None, alias='Edges')
```

without the default value, it breaks because the optional does not override that the field is required and needs a default value. Which is the solution I used to overcome this problem while using Pydantic with fast API  to manage  mongo  resources

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```py
class MedicalFolderUpdate(RWModel):
    id : str = Field(alias='_id')
    university : Optional[str] = Field(alias='school')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you will want to use [Pydantic's `Field` function](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/schema/#field-customization) to specify the info for your optional field. Also, must enable population fields by alias by setting `allow_population_by_field_name` in the [model `Config`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/model_config/#options):

```py
from typing import Optional


class MedicalFolderUpdate(BaseModel):
    id: str = Field(alias='_id')
    university: Optional[str] = Field(alias="school")

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
```

By default, value for `university` will be `None`. If you want to exclude unset values, you can do so when serializing to json or dict like so:

```py
raw_data = {"id": "abc"}
row = MedicalFolderUpdate.parse_obj(raw_data)

# default, university is None
print(row.dict())  # {'id': 'abc', 'university': None}

# exclude from serialization
print(row.dict(exclude_unset=True))  # {'id': 'abc'}
```